# Have an error when trying to update information

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error in my code. Exactly when I'm trying to **execute** request there is "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement". What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
require_once "db_connect.php";

if(isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) {
$id = $_POST["id"];


$sql = DB::prepare("UPDATE objects SET name=?, description=?, ab_name=?, ab_email=?, approved_by=?, location=?, address=?, domain=?, phone=?, worktime=?,
 price=?, ex_description=?, update_time=?, area=?, category=?, city=?, subway=? WHERE id='" .$_POST["id"]. "';");

if($sql->execute()){
header("location: /www/public_html2/adminconfirm.php");
exit();
}else{
//echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
 printf("Error: %s.\n", $sql->error);
 var_dump($sql->execute());

}
}
?>
```

Comment: the post id should be also a WHERE id= ? and where do you bind you variables?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using prepared statements, you need to use `bind_param` method to bind variables to question marks in your query. In fact, mysql expects variables for each question mark when you execute it.
Take a look at:
[prepared statements manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)